# How to test menu item using Jubula

Tags: jubula

I'm a beginner for developing intelliJ plugins. I've already established connection from Jubula to my AUT.

I want to write a test suite, to check the availability of a sub menu item in intelliJ.

Please assist me.

Comment: Could you tell more details about where are you stuck? Do you have a working Jubula+AUT setup? What's working already from your test?

Comment: "Jubula+AUT" working fine. Let's assume, I have added a sub menu item to Tools-> abcMenu-> xyzSubMenu. In this Scenario I want to check the availability of the component and selectability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to dig too deep into Jubula, then all you have to do is use the Observation Mode (camera icon) and record clicking on your menu item.

When the test is executed it will do exactly the same; it will mark the test failed if the menu can not be clicked.

Answer (score 2):

There's also a cheat sheet on how to test menus available via Help/Cheat Sheets. The documentation for testing menus is here:
https://testing.bredex.de/files/content/software/documentation/reference/components/ch03s02s05.html

(the link to each action description is at the bottom of the page)